How to pass a variable to an alert in SwiftUI
On change of a variable, I want to pass the old value and new value to an alert as user action in the alert will change how to proceed. Something like this:
.onChange(of: value) { [oldValue = value] newValue in
            if (values.contains(newValue)) { resultsExistAlert = true }
            ...
            
            .alert("This value already exists. Would you like to edit the new value or keep editing the old value?", isPresented: $resultsExistAlert) {
                Button("New Value") {
                    values = viewModel.data.results.filter{ $0 == newValue }
                    dismiss()
                }
                Button("Old Value") {
                    value = oldValue
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }

However, an alert cannot exist inside of the onChange block, so I will have to move it. So how do I pass newValue and oldValue to the alert when it is outside of that block?

There is alert(_:isPresented:presenting:actions:message:) which takes also a type along with the Bool. You could create a custom struct containing the old and new value and a @State property then pass this in the presenting parameter.

Make a struct that contains the old and new value and then set it as a state and have the alert present that data.
